# How to write values in a dictionary as a list

Tags: python, dictionary

My code so far is

```
class_1={"Bob":[5,3,4,5,6,7],"Jack":[4],"Rob":[7]}
class_2={"Alex":[5],"Steve":[4],"John":[7]}
class_3={"Adrien":[5],"Morgan":[3]}

score=int(input("Enter a number"))
name=input("What is your name?")
userClass=int(input("class?"))
if userClass ==1:
    if name in class_1:
        class_1[name].append(score)
    else:
        class_1[name]=score
elif userClass ==2:
    if name in class_2:
        class_2[name].append(score)
    else:
        class_2[name]=score
elif userclass ==3:
    if name in class_3:
        class_3[name].append(score)
    else:
        class_3[name]=score
```

the problem is that whenever i enter a name that is not in any of the dictionaries, it adds the number(the value) as an integer and not in list format. This prevents me later on from ordering the scores because they are different formats.

Please help me! i have been trying for hours.

Answer (score 3):

One easy solution is to just insert a list into the dict:

```
if userClass ==1:
    if name in class_1:
        class_1[name].append(score)
    else:
        class_1[name]=[score]
```

But using [default dicts](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) would probably be more pythonic and also solve that problem. E.g.

```
from collections import defaultdict
class_1 = defaultdict(list)
for name, score in [("Bob", [5,3,4,5,6,7]), [...]]:
    class_1[name].append(score)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up an empty list before you can append to it. Try changing `class_1[name]=score` to `class_1[name]=[score]`. That will create a list with one integer element, which you can then subsequently append to.

Comment: is there a way to work out the average of the list or find the highest value from the list

Comment: Yes -- max (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) and numpy.mean (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html)

Comment: See the higher voted answer, default dicts is a better fit for your use case

Comment: why is that? are there any downsides to your way of doing it

Comment: I think our answers are the same, but @syntonym's tip on using default dicts would simplify your code.